# Ionic 3 Post Camera Image to API With cordova-plugin-file

Tags: ionic3

I have been successfully using cordova-plugin-file-transfer to post an image file from a device camera to an API e.g. fileTransfer.upload(fileUrl, url, options).

However, cordova-plugin-file-transfer has now been deprecated:
"With the new features introduced in XMLHttpRequest, this plugin is not needed any more. Migrating from this plugin to using the new features of XMLHttpRequest, is explained in this Cordova blog post."
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

The suggested new approach is to use cordova-plugin-file and XMLHttpRequest. 
https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
    console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
    fs.root.getFile('bot.png', { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                // Create a blob based on the FileReader "result", which we asked to be retrieved as an ArrayBuffer
                var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], { type: "image/png" });
                var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                oReq.open("POST", "http://mysweeturl.com/upload_handler", true);
                oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
                    // all done!
                };
                // Pass the blob in to XHR's send method
                oReq.send(blob);
            };
            // Read the file as an ArrayBuffer
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }, function (err) { console.error('error getting fileentry file!' + err); });
    }, function (err) { console.error('error getting file! ' + err); });
}, function (err) { console.error('error getting persistent fs! ' + err); });
```

In the example above, we can replace XMLHttpRequest with Angular 5 HttpClient e.g.

```
this.http.post(path, body, options);
```

The cordova-plugin-camera docs suggest using DestinationType = FILE_URI or NATIVE_URI which both return a path/file similar to the following: content://media/external/images/media/1249. They specifically warn against returning a base64 encoded string.

"Return base64 encoded string. DATA_URL can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors. Use FILE_URI or NATIVE_URI if possible"
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_Camera.DestinationType

It seems like the new/correct approach here is to use the cordova-plugin-file to get the file, turn this file into a blob, and then post it to the API.

First, I think I need to convert the camera localFile using resolveLocalFilesystemUrl from cordova-plugin-file: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/.

```
this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(localFile).then((entry) => {
    console.log(entry.fullPath);
});
```

Android Example:

```
localFile: content://media/external/images/media/1249
resolvedLocalFile: content://media/external/images/media/1827
```

However, I've been unable to use the resolvedLocalFile with cordova-plugin-file to get the file and convert to blob (and then finally post to API).

Is this the correct approach? If so, what's a working code example of this. If not, what's the correct approach? Note that I've seen examples posting base64 encoded strings but cordova-plugin-camera explicitly warns against this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a working stub based on the approach: use cordova-plugin-file to get the file, convert file to blob, post blob to API. This post was also very helpful in creating this stub: https://golb.hplar.ch/2017/02/Uploading-pictures-from-Ionic-2-to-Spring-Boot.html

Main routine:

```
this.cameraProvider.getPicture()
    .flatMap(imageData => {
        return this.cameraProvider.imageDataToBlob(imageData);
    })
    .flatMap(blob => {
        return this.workerProvider.updateImage(blob);
    }).subscribe();
```

Get file using cordova-plugin-camera:

```
public getPicture(): Observable<any> {

    const options: CameraOptions = {
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    }

    return Observable.fromPromise(
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
                return this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData: any) => {

                    // Android DestinationType.FILE_URI returns a local image url in this form: content://media/external/images/media/1249
                    // iOS DestinationType.FILE_URI returns a local image url in this form: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/25A3F622-38DB-4701-AB20-90AAE9AC02C8/tmp/cdv_photo_002.jpg
                    return imageData;

                }).catch((error) => {
                    // Handle error.
                })
            }
            else {
                return Observable.of(null);
            }
        })
    )
}
```

Convert file to blob:

```
public imageDataToBlob(imageData): Observable<any> {

    return Observable.fromPromise(this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(imageData))
        .flatMap((fileEntry: FileEntry) => { // Cast entry to fileEntry.
            return this.fileEntryToObservable(fileEntry)
        })
        .flatMap((file) => {
            return this.fileReaderToObservable(file)
        });
}

public fileEntryToObservable(fileEntry: any): Observable<any> {

    return Observable.create(observer => {
        // Success.
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            observer.next(file);
        },
        // Error.
        function (error) {
            observer.error(error)
        })
    });
}

public fileReaderToObservable(file: any): Observable<any> {

    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    return Observable.create(observer => {
        // Success.
        fileReader.onload = ev => {
            let formData = new FormData();
            let imgBlob = new Blob([fileReader.result], { type: file.type });
            observer.next(imgBlob);
        }
        // Error.
        fileReader.onerror = error => observer.error(error);
    });
}
```

Post blob to API:

```
// Do NOT add Content-Type multipart/form-data to header.
let headers = new HttpHeaders()

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob, 'image');

let options = { headers: headers };
return this.http.post(url, formData, options);
```